# using web references

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, soap

So been a few days now learning about web references within my projects I have now came across a strange problem.

Using a simple console app I did this:

```
namespace Webservices09004961
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            {
                Convert.ConvertTemperatureSoapClient client =
                new Convert.ConvertTemperatureSoapClient();
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter temperature in Celsius: ");
                    double tempC = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    double tempF = client.ConvertTemp(tempC, Convert.TemperatureUnit.degreeCelsius, Convert.TemperatureUnit.degreeFahrenheit);
                    Console.WriteLine("That is " + tempF + " degrees Farenheit");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have added in the service reference "Convert" related to this link:
http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertTemperature.asmx?WSDL

**However I get this error:**

> An endpoint configuration section for contract 'Convert.ConvertTemperatureSoap' could not be loaded because more than
>   one endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please
>   indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name.

Is this because you can only have one service reference allocated at any one time? The reason I ask is because my local service reference within the same project build still works fine? Yet this one doesnt? (It did when I first created it)

Or is this a seperate problem?

Also what are the limitations on SOAP?

Comment: The answer will be in your .config file.

Comment: Yeah I found it. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This errors are common when you try to remove a svc reference and add it again. Check your app/web.config file, you should have duplicate entries for Convert.ConvertTemperatureSoap. remove one of them and it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Davita I found it :)

Comment: Lol This Answer has saved me twice!

Answer (score 0):

```
        <endpoint address="http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertTemperature.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ConvertTemperatureSoap"
            contract="Convert.ConvertTemperatureSoap" name="ConvertTemperatureSoap" />
        <!--<endpoint address="http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertTemperature.asmx"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ConvertTemperatureSoap12"
            contract="Convert.ConvertTemperatureSoap" name="ConvertTemperatureSoap12" />-->
```

Its ok I found the error was related to a double entry in my config file. Strange not sure why it did that.

Works now.